# Detect when an absolute element goes outside of a container

Tags: javascript

I am attemping to create a randomize function which will randomize my ships positions (the red containers) inside of its parent container. However, I don't know how to set a condition that will detect when a container goes outside of its parent element.

How do you check the position of an element in relation to its parent container? I can't seem to find the syntax to do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Battleship</title>
    <style>

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body, html {
            height: 50rem;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        body {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        h1{
            color: white;
            margin: 3rem 0 1rem 0;
        }
        #messageBoard{
            color: white;
            margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
        }
        #shipContainer {
            width: 20rem;
            height: 7.5rem;
            background-color: rgba(17, 13, 236, 0);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            position: relative;
        }
        .shipDivs{
            width: 10%;
            height: 25%;
            border: 1px solid rgba(212, 212, 221, 0.116);
        }
        .battleship{
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color:rgba(18, 26, 4, 0.425);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .cruiser {
            position: absolute;
            left: 20%;
            width: 10%;
            height: 75%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color:rgba(18, 26, 4, 0.425);
        }
        .spyShip{
            position: absolute;
            left: 40%;
            width: 10%;
            height: 25%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color:rgba(18, 26, 4, 0.425);
        }
        .spyShip2 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 40%;
            top: 50%;
            width: 10%;
            height: 25%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color:rgba(18, 26, 4, 0.425);
        }
        #wrapper {
            width: 20rem;
            height: 20rem;
            margin: 2.5rem 0 0 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: flex-start;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: rgba(17, 13, 236, 0);
        }
        .squares {
            border: 1px solid rgba(212, 212, 221, 0.5);
            width: 10%;
            height: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>BattleShip!</h1>
<p id="messageBoard">Place Your Ships!</p>
</div>
<div id="shipContainer">
    <div class="battleship"></div>
    <div class="cruiser"></div>
    <div class="spyShip"></div>
    <div class="spyShip2"></div>
    <div class="spyShip3"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
    <script>
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
        const box = document.getElementsByClassName('.box');
        const div = document.querySelector('div');
        const shipContainer = document.querySelector('#shipContainer')

        let x = 1;
        let y = 1;

        mathRdm100 = function(){
           return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 10;  
        }

        console.log(mathRdm100())

        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){
            let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList = `shipDivs`;
                shipContainer.appendChild(div);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList = `squares`;
                wrapper.appendChild(div);
                x++
                y++
        }

        randomPosition = function(){
            let position = mathRdm100();
            document.querySelector('.battleship').style.left = `${mathRdm100()}%`;
            document.querySelector('.battleship').style.right = `${mathRdm100()}%`;
            document.querySelector('.battleship').style.bottom = `${mathRdm100()}%`;
            document.querySelector('.battleship').style.top = `${mathRdm100()}%`;

        //     if (document.querySelector('.battleship') ????   ){
        //         console.log('true');
        //     }else {
        //         console.log('false');
        //     }
        }

        randomPosition()

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a need to use `position: absolute`? This would be a lot easier to calculate using `position: relative`.

Comment: There may be. I only used position absolute because I read you needed to do that to make it 'dragable'. That could be wrong though, I am still trying to learn and figure this out.